# How can I unlock slime science gadgets?

Tags: slime-rancher

I would like to know how can I unlock the Slime Science gadgets.
Anybody has a clue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to unlock the lab, which costs 10,000 Newbucks.  After you unlock the lab, you can begin to purchase blueprints for the gadgets you wish to make, and then you can finally make them.  The Lab is located behind your house and off to the left some if you are looking at the front door of your house.

Looking at the Lab, to the left is the machine that you purchase the blueprints from using Newbucks.  You can also unlock blueprints from [treasure pods](http://slimerancher.wikia.com/wiki/Treasure_pods).  In the center of the lab is [The Refinery](http://slimerancher.wikia.com/wiki/Slime_Science#The_Refinery).  The Refinery takes accepts plorts and other resources that you can find via gadgets.  Using the plorts and resources gathered, you can build the gadgets by using [The Fabricator](http://slimerancher.wikia.com/wiki/Slime_Science#The_Fabricator), which is on the right side of the lab.

To place a gadget, press <kbd>T</kbd> or down on the D-Pad if on console.  This will open gadget interface, which allows you to see all the spots around the world which you can place gadgets.  Walk up to one of these spots, and press <kbd>E</kbd> or X if on Console.  This will open a new menu of all of your gadgets in your inventory which you can select and place in the spot.

See the [Slime Science Wiki page](http://slimerancher.wikia.com/wiki/Slime_Science) for more information.

Comment: @ACM I updated my post further.  This should explain everything now.

Comment: @acm don't forget to upvote/accept an answer that you found helpful.  Welcome to Arqade!

Comment: Sorry, but I want to know how you got advanced gadgets.

Comment: @ACM like what exactly? It's starting to become unclear what you are asking.  Your question only stated gadgets.  Now you are changing it.

Comment: Sorry, ACM is my 10 years old son. He is not fluent in English yet. I'll help him on his questions here. I appreciate your kindly support.